# jQuery Select2 Style Updates Change CSS Class style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2, stylesheet

How can I change default style of `JQuery Select2` component.

Default styling is not matching with existing page design.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here, are some JS tricks I found for my work around:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#area_data').select2({
  'allowClear': false,
  dropdownAutoWidth : false,
  width: '100%'
});
```

Hope it helps !

[Click here for more details](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)